# Custom functions for common string functions

Tags: function, numbers, lowercase

I need to write functions without using the built in Python functions for the following:

- if the string is all alphabetic characters
- if the string is all uppercase
- if the string is all numbers
- swaps the upper and lowercase characters
- converts all characters to lowercase

I've been trying to figure it out for a while and can't come up with much.
Anyone have any hints?

Answer (score 0):

For most of them I used ASCII values for logic and conversions.

```
def is_up_case(string):
    """Shows whether or not all characters in a string are uppercase"""
    for character in string:
        if not (65 <= ord(character) <= 90) and (character != " "):  # only allows capital letters and spaces
            return False
    return True


def is_low_case(string):
    """Shows whether or not all characters in a string are lowercase"""
    for character in string:
        if not (97 <= ord(character) <= 122) and (character != " "):
            return False
    return True


def is_alpha(string):
    """Shows whether or not all characters in a string are alphabetical"""
    for character in string:
        if not (97 <= ord(character) <= 122) and not (65 <= ord(character) <= 90) and (character != " "):
            return False
    return True


def up_case(string):
    """Converts letters to uppercase"""
    new_str = ""
    for character in string:
        ascii_val = ord(character)
        if 97 <= ascii_val <= 122:
            ascii_val -= 32  # 32 is the distance between ASCII values of each lowercase and its uppercase companion
        new_str += chr(ascii_val)
    return new_str


def low_case(string):
    """Converts letters to lowercase"""
    new_str = ""
    for character in string:
        ascii_val = ord(character)
        if 65 <= ascii_val <= 90:
            ascii_val += 32
        new_str += chr(ascii_val)
    return new_str


def swap_case(string):
    """Swaps uppercase to lowercase and vice versa"""
    new_str = ""
    for character in string:
        ascii_val = ord(character)
        if 65 <= ascii_val <= 90:
            ascii_val += 32
        elif 97 <= ascii_val <= 122:
            ascii_val -= 32
        else:
            pass
        new_str += chr(ascii_val)
    return new_str


def is_numbers(string):  # I could have used ASCII values with this one too, but I wanted to spice it up ;)
    """Shows if all numbers in a string can be converted to integers"""
    try:
        int(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:  # if it fails to convert the whole statement into integers, it will return False
        return False  # spaces will also cause it to return as False
```

Hope this helps!